# How to load/create a level/room from a text file in java?

Tags: java, file, 2d

Basically each room has a size of 10 by 10, the "W" represents the Walls, and the blank spaces -" " represent the Floor, and the numbers are Doors.I figured the best way to create the room is to create a method that receives a file and reads it and put its "information" into a String[10][10], and then create another method(or just do it in my Main) that receives the String[10][10] created and creates the room(adds the images to the room), but i am having some difficulties reading the file so if you guys could help me with that part i would be thankful. 
Here is the type of text files from which i want to create my  room:

```
    WWWW0WWWWW
    W        W
    W        W
    W        W
    W        W
    W       WW
    W       WW
    W       WW
    W       W1
    WWWWWWWWWW
```

Here are the Door, Wall and Floor classes:

```
public class Door implements ImageTile {


 private Position position;

public Door(Position position) {
    this.position = position;
}

@Override
public String getName() {
    return "Door";
}

@Override
public Position getPosition() {
    return position;
}
```

}

```
 public class Floor implements ImageTile {


private Position position;

public Floor(Position position) {
    this.position = position;
}

@Override
public String getName() {
    return "Floor";
}

@Override
public Position getPosition() {
    return position;
}
```

}

```
public class Wall implements ImageTile {


private Position position;

public Wall(Position position) {
    this.position = position;
}

@Override
public String getName() {
    return "Wall";
}

@Override
public Position getPosition() {
    return position;
}
```

}

And this is my method for adding images to my frame:

```
    public void newImages(final List<ImageTile> newImages) {
    if (newImages == null)
        return;
    if (newImages.size() == 0)
        return;
    for (ImageTile i : newImages) {
        if (!imageDB.containsKey(i.getName())) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("No such image in DB " + i.getName());
        }
    }
    images.addAll(newImages);
    frame.repaint();
}
```

If you guys could help me i would appreciate it very much, thanks guys.Her is what i have now:

```
     public class Room {
       private String[][]room;

       public Room(){
        room = new String[10][10]; }

     public static Room fromFile(File file){     
    if(file.exists()){
        Scanner sc = null;     
        Room room = new Room();
        try {
            sc = new Scanner(file);
            while(sc.hasNextLine()){
                if(sc.nextLine().startsWith("#"))
                    sc.nextLine();
                else{  
                    String[] s0 = sc.nextLine().split("");
                 //Here is where my trouble is, i dont know how to add the content of this String s0 to the String s
                   if(s0.length==10){
                       for(int x = 0; x < 10; x++){
                                for(int y = 0; y < 10; y++){
                                    String[x][y] s= String[x] s0;
                }         
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Ficheiro "+file.getAbsolutePath()+
                    " não existe. ");           }
        finally{
            if(sc!=null)sc.close();
        }
    }
    else
        System.out.println("Ficheiro "+file.getAbsolutePath()+
                " não existe. ");       
    return null;        
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  "... _I figured the best way to create the room is to create a method that receives a file and reads it and put its "information" into a String[10][10], and then create another method ... that receives the String[10][10] created and creates the room ... but i am having some difficulties reading the file so if you guys could help me with that part_ ..."   What code you have provided is interesting, but has almost nothing to do with your problem.  You need to at least attempt to write code for reading a file into a String[10][10] before you ask for help here.

Comment: i have some i will add it right now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each call to `sc.nextLine()` is reading another line from your file.  You need to save the line into a temporary variable, and then refer to that temporary.

Maintain a counter of lines you've processed, so you can fill in the appropriate line in your `s[][]` matrix.

You only need to allocate storage for the 10 rows, since splitting the line you read in will result in an array of strings (the columns in one row) being allocated for you.

```
int row = 0;
String[][] s = new String[10][];
while(sc.hasNextLine() && i < 10) {
    String line = sc.nextLine();
    if( !line.startsWith("#")) {
        String[] s0 = sc.line.split("");
        s[row] = s0;
        row++;
    }         
}
```

BTW, Use `String[][]` is overkill; since each string will only hold one character.  Perhaps you could consider using `char[][]`.  And `line.toCharArray()` would split the `line` into a `char[]` for you.

---

**EDIT**: (Due to edit of your question's code)

Instead of:

```
if(s0.length==10){
    for(int x = 0; x < 10; x++){
        for(int y = 0; y < 10; y++){
            String[x][y] s= String[x] s0;
        }         
    }
}
```

you want:

```
if(s0.length==10){
    for(int y = 0; y < 10; y++){
        s[row][y] = s0[y];
    }
    row++;
}
```

With `row` being the row counter in my above code.

Comment: Thanks for the help immensily, but one thing i made a mistake in copying the work i had,instead of having a String[][] s i have an object of type room, is it the same way?

Comment: I already changed the code to show how i construct the room(which is basically a String[10][10]

Comment: Your `Room` class appears to be just have a `String[ ][ ] room` field.  So, yes, you could instead do `Room r = new Room();` at the top of your `fromFile()` function, and store the values as `r.room[row][y] = s0[y];`.